# Ajax, filters and shortcodes

Tags: filters, shortcode, ajax, gallery

could you figure out why I'm unable to get shortcode filters applied in ajax inclusion of posts?

Let me explain better: I've managed to include a post from within another post, through **admin-ajax.php**, as recommended in the famous [5 tips](http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/).

Obviously I don't want to display the shortcode tags, nor I'd like to strip them, so I'm echoing `do_shortcode($post->post_content)`

At this point, the post gallery gets rendered but *unfiltered*, even though I'm running the "Cleaner Gallery" plugin, which starts with `add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'cleaner_gallery', 10, 2 );` and succesfully works in normal (non-ajax) posts.

I've been trying to debug this issue by replacing

```
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;
```

with

```
$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
echo 'FILTERED OUTPUT = '.$output.' !';
    if ( $output != '' )
        return $output;
```

inside the **function gallery_shortcode($attr)** located in *wp-includes/media.php*.
It seems that it runs twice, but in ajax inclusions the output is empty at first time and then it's not filtered.

Well, in all effect it happens that also the "2nd round" echoed output I mentioned remains empty when setting again **add_filter** before **do_shortcode**; otherwise it's shown (but, as I said, unfiltered).

I've also tried to track it with

```
echo has_filter('post_gallery');
echo current_filter();
```

and I've discovered that ***has*** returns always ***1***, while ***current*** first returns '***post-gallery***' as expected, and then it gets overwritten by the '***wp_ajax_nopriv_etc***' hook, which is required to handle requests with *admin-ajax.php* but it's actually an **action** and **not** a **filter**. (?!?)

I've also tried without success to hack the cleaner gallery plugin, in order to make it directly run the shortcode without filtering the default function, removed the originary shortcode and added that new one.
It works like a charm for normal posts, but it seems there is no way to implement the plugin in ajax requests.

I'm getting more and more confused.
Please help me!

(also posted on the [WP.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcodes-filters-and-ajax))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awww...
in **admin-ajax.php**:

```
define('WP_ADMIN', true);
```

in **cleaner-gallery.php**:

```
function cleaner_gallery_setup() {    
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        require_once( CLEANER_GALLERY_DIR . 'admin.php' );
    } else {
        require_once( CLEANER_GALLERY_DIR . 'gallery.php' );
    }
}
```

So I have to manually include & run the necessary plugin code skipped after checking the WP_ADMIN constant, but I guess the need for a frontend ajax handler is becoming increasingly urgent!

Answer (score 2):

When WordPress displays post content, it's not running `do_shortcode()` on the post content, it's running `apply_filters( 'the_content', $content )`.  Shortcode filters are applied on `the_content` filter, which is why you have to add extra filters to get them to work in widgets or the footer or elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, but when including an Ajax request I guess that **do_shortcode()** is required to render something more than a raw bracketed shortcode output. According to your suggestion, I've added `apply_filters('the_content',$content);` but it leads to the same result. Should I do something else? However, it seems that the **post_gallery** filter hook is applied, but the _Cleaner Gallery_ filter is not added to it.

Comment: I can't add again this filter to process the content retrieved through Ajax since it should apply only on the shortcode part...

Comment: Just to be clearer I must point out that the ordinary `[gallery]` shortcode do work in both normal and ajax pages. What I'm trying to achieve is to get it filtered since the function `gallery_shortcode($attr)` runs `$output = apply_filters('post_gallery', '', $attr);
if ( $output != '' )
 return $output;` to _"Allow plugins/themes to override the default gallery template"_; when a custom hacked plugin shortcode replaces/overrides the default shortcode, it fails and it looks like the plugin is invisible to the Ajax handler. (Ah, good ol' separate PHP file!)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you worked around a solution, but i had a similar problem and solved by:

- unbinding the original gallery function from the gallery shortcode
- binding my own gallery function to the original gallery shortcode (instead of creating a new shortcode for a custom gallery function)

  ```
  //unbinds WordPress function in order to replace it with new code
  remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');
  //binds own custom gallery code function
  add_shortcode('gallery', 'acmecustomgallery_shortcode');
  ```

More details [here](http://celsobessa.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/tech-talk-using-wordpress-gallery-shortcode-and-ajax-with-no-headaches/).

Comment: Celso, [this is not Twitter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29518/can-and-should-stack-overflow-automatically-rewrite-bit-ly-links), you can use full links instead of shortened ones, thanks! +1 for the simple and fast solution.