# How to get gallery id inserted to a post?

Tags: shortcode, ajax, gallery

Is it possible to get a specific Gallery ID inserted to a post in wordpress 3.5? I want to load gallery from post using Ajax. I use shortcode `[gallery]` to do it. But when I use it this way:

```
echo do_shortcode('[gallery id="'.$_POST['postid'].'"]');
```

I get all images attached to the post with $_POST['postid'] and not images from the gallery which is inserted to that post.

Comment: Have a look here, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/ajax-filters-and-shortcodes and here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277794/wordpress-3-5-own-gallery-with-included-images-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2):

In single.php i put this code, from this link (thank you Wyck) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277794/wordpress-3-5-own-gallery-with-included-images-doesnt-work

```
preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
$array_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
print_r($array_id);
```

Now I can use gallery shortcode [gallery ids=" id's from $array_id here "]

Answer (score 0):

The plain, old [gallery] should still work here.